# eSATAp combo port compatability dell Dell Latitude E6420

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, esata

I need to know what sort of compatibility eSATAp (Power over eSATA) ports have with SATA 2 and SATA 3 drives. I'm helping a friend get an external for his laptop and he has an e-sata usb combo port on it that we intend to use. Wikipedia claims it'll work with SATA 3, but I was looking for something more concrete.

This seems related [Dell eSATAp not working with some SATA disks](https://superuser.com/questions/402530/dell-esatap-not-working-with-some-sata-disks)

Does this mean it can run just about any SATA drive, so long as there is an external power source for the external drive?

Comment: I have used the eSATA port on a Dell Latitude E6400 and E6500 without any problems. Both with a pendrive (throttle 16GB), an external case with a WD black 320 (laptop drive) and via a eSATA dock (power!) for 3.5 inch WD black drives. Granted, neither of those are precisely E6420, but they are the older models of the same set.

Comment: I'm using this [$10 cable - eSATAp to SATA power and data](http://www.amazon.com/eSATAp-Power-eSATA-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00FHN1CZC/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1414448268&sr=8-1) on the other end. I have an OCZ Agility 3 SSD (120GB) attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it will work with any sata, there are even some [adapters](http://www.compos.cz/delock-adapter-sata-22-pin-samice-esatapd-samice_d260649.html). It's an esata with aditional power from usb, but you can use regular esata connector.